# Collect results of 2 parallel Publishers in Flowable

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I'm quite new with reactive programming but trying to apply rxjava for collecting call and sms lists and combine into single one. The idea is to iterate cursor in parallel manner with sequential items emitting. 
After this all items are gathered into single list.

But in `doOnComplete` not all the data is collected (I have around 150 items and there're only ~25 added). 
I believe that the issue is that `Flowable.concat` doesn't wait for all items but that's only a suggestion.

```
public void readLatestActivity() {
    Cursor callsCursor = getCallsCursor();
    Cursor smsCursor = getSmsCursor();

    if (callsCursor == null || smsCursor == null) {
        return;
    }

    SortedSet<MActivity> activities = new TreeSet<>((left, right) -> left.getReceiveTime() < right.getReceiveTime() ? 1 : 0);

    Flowable.concat(getCallsPublisher(callsCursor), getSmsPublisher(smsCursor))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(new Consumer<MActivity>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull MActivity mActivity) throws Exception {
                    if (mActivity != null){
                        activities.add(mActivity);
                    }
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnComplete(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    Timber.d("doOnComplete");
                    callsCursor.close();
                    smsCursor.close();
                    mBus.post(new EActivities(activities)); //<--- here I'm getting ~25 items
                }
            })
            .subscribe();
}

private Publisher<MActivity> getCallsPublisher(Cursor callsCursor) {
    return Flowable.fromIterable(RxCursorIterable.from(callsCursor))
            .take(callsCursor.getCount() < LIMIT ? callsCursor.getCount() : LIMIT)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .map((Function<Cursor, MActivity>) this::readCallFromCursor)
            .sequential()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

}

private Publisher<MActivity> getSmsPublisher(Cursor smsCursor) {
    return Flowable.fromIterable(RxCursorIterable.from(smsCursor))
            .take(smsCursor.getCount() < LIMIT ? smsCursor.getCount() : LIMIT)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .map((Function<Cursor, MActivity>) this::readSmsFromCursor)
            .sequential()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Methods for reading sms and calls working fine. I believe issue lies somewhere else.

Also I've found a class which makes `cursor` act like `Iterable`

```
public class RxCursorIterable implements Iterable<Cursor> {

private Cursor mIterableCursor;

public RxCursorIterable(Cursor c) {
    mIterableCursor = c;
}

public static RxCursorIterable from(Cursor c) {
    return new RxCursorIterable(c);
}

@Override
public Iterator<Cursor> iterator() {
    return RxCursorIterator.from(mIterableCursor);
}

private static class RxCursorIterator implements Iterator<Cursor> {

    private final Cursor mCursor;

    public RxCursorIterator(Cursor cursor) {
        mCursor = cursor;
    }

    public static Iterator<Cursor> from(Cursor cursor) {
        return new RxCursorIterator(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !mCursor.isClosed() && mCursor.moveToNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor next() {
        return mCursor;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the comparator you use when creating `TreeSet`. It does not return `-1` when `left.getReceiveTime() > right.getReceiveTime()`, i.e. some activities are erroneously considered duplicate.

I would also suggest simplifying your `getCallsPublisher` code like this:

```
return Flowable.generate(getCallsCursor(),
        (cursor, emitter) -> {
            if (!cursor.isClosed() && cursor.moveToNext())
                emitter.onNext(readCallFromCursor(cursor));
            else
                emitter.onComplete();
        }, Cursor::close)
    .take(LIMIT);
```

And getting rid of `RxCursorIterable`.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Could you please write this snippet without lambda because I'd like to understand which functions you are using.

Comment: @AnZ I am using this function: `generate(initialState, generator, disposeState)` http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#generate(java.util.concurrent.Callable,%20io.reactivex.functions.BiConsumer,%20io.reactivex.functions.Consumer)